# Running OpenGL on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I wish to run some basic OpenGL programs however on compiling with g++ I get the error

```
fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
```

I have the following headers in my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

How can I run OpenGL on Windows 10? I could not find any resources on Internet detailing what exactly to do with binary files for GLEW and GLFW.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Download and extract GLEW binaries if you have not already from 
   http://glew.sourceforge.net/
2. Go to Project Properties
3. Select C/C++
4. In the 'Additional Include Directories', add the path to '...glew\include' 
   folder[image]

Comment: Any method to run it directly without Visual Studio.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Till now, I was using VS Code for everything. This was for a course on design practices which had expected us to do everything from scratch even makefiles. So I wanted help in how to compile the code directly through terminal.

Comment: go to c_cpp_properties.json and add the include path under "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": ["<glew include directory>"]
    }
]

Comment: can you post the snippet of c_cpp_properties.json?

Comment: "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++","C:/OpenGL/glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN32/include/GLFW","C:/OpenGL/glew-2.1.0/include/GL"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],

Comment: You are pointing to "...glew-2.1.0/include/GL". Change it to "...glew-2.1.0/include". Hope it helps, cheers

Answer (score -2):

The issue resolved by adding environment variable CPATH and adding the path for GLEW and GLFW include folders to it.